# multiple functions in one endpoint fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to create an audio server where I can upload various audio files, I have a requirement that I can only create one endpoint for creating, I have come up with this but it does show the request form to input data.

```
class AudioType(str, Enum):
    Song = "Song"
    Podcast = "Podcast"
    Audiobook = "Audiobook"


@app.post("/{audio_type}", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
def audio(audio_type: AudioType):
    if audio_type == AudioType.Song:
        def create_song(request: schemas.Song, db: Session = Depends(database.get_db)):
            new_song = models.Song(name=request.name, duration=request.duration, uploadTime=request.uploadTime)
            db.add(new_song)
            db.commit()
            db.refresh(new_song)
            return new_song
    elif audio_type == AudioType.Podcast:
        def create_podcast(request: schemas.Podcast, db: Session = Depends(database.get_db)):
            new_podcast = models.Podcast(name=request.name,  duration=request.duration, uploadTime=request.uploadTime,                                         host=request.host)
            db.add(new_podcast)
            db.commit()
            db.refresh(new_podcast)
            return new_podcast
    elif audio_type == AudioType.Audiobook:
        def create_audiobook(request: schemas.Audiobook, db: Session = Depends(database.get_db)):
            new_audiobook = models.Audiobook(titile=request.title, author=request.author, narrator=request.narrator,                                              duration=request.duration, uploadTime=request.uploadTime)
            db.add(new_audiobook)
            db.commit()
            db.refresh(new_audiobook)
            return new_audiobook
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method doesn't accept the `request` object but only the `audio_type`.
Also from what I understand from your code, you may have multiple request bodies (`schemas` as you refer to them)

There are 2 options to what you want:

1. You need to declare your endpoint as follows:

   ```
   from typing import Union

   @app.post("/{audio_type}", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
   def audio(
       request: Union[schemas.Song, schemas.Podcast, 
       schemas.Audiobook], audio_type: AudioType
   ):
       ... Your method ...
   ```

   But the auto swagger of fastapi will not provide a schema example and you will have to provide examples manually, (which may or may not be possible, I don't really know and haven't tried it :/)
2. OR you can have a schema that can accept everything as `Optional` and the `audio_type` parameter:

   ```
   from typing import Optional


   class EndpointSchema(BaseModel):
       audio_type: AudioType
       song: Optional[schemas.Song]
       podcast: Optional[schemas.Podcast]
       audiobook: Optional[schemas.Audiobook]


   @app.post("/audio", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
   def audio(request_body: EndpointSchema):
       if request_body.audio_type == AudioType.Song:
           ... Continue with your request processing ...
   ```

Finally, **very important**: You are declaring internal methods (`create_song` etc.) that you are not calling afterward, so your code will do nothing. You **don't** need to do that, use the code you want to create a song, podcast, or audiobook directly inside the `if, elif ...` blocks!

Comment: Thank you for your response, once i have made the request as Union, i want to know how to access them in model.song() ?

Comment: @devgru You can access them from the `request_body` object.

Comment: so i tried the union solution, you were correct the swagger UI only shows schema of first parameter, in the second solution it showed all the schemas. is there a way it can show me the schema of only one specified audio type

Comment: @devgru I don't know fo sure, but I think that you will have to manually extend the open API for that endpoint: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/

Comment: i read this but i don't know where to go from here. can you provide more context ?